# how can i create a php file that runs php artisan migrate command?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I want to create a php file in public directory that runs php artisan migrate:fresh (--seed) command in server. when I upload my project to FTP server I want to open that link (ex: [www.project.com/migration.php](http://www.project.com/migration.php)) and that file should run migration and/or seed files. is it possible
if it is how can I do that?

btw I use Laravel 7.28 version

Comment: You should probably add it to your deploy script rather than adding it to an endpoint (why on earth would you do that?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call artisan commands like this in functions or even in routes!

```
public function callArtisanCommands()
{
    \Artisan::call('cache:clear');
    \Artisan::call('view:clear');
    \Artisan::call('route:clear');
    \Artisan::call('migrate:fresh');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a route that calls the Artisan command:

```
Route::get('migrate', function () {
    $exitCode = Artisan::call('migrate:fresh --seed --force');
});
```

Added the `--force` parameter because in a `production` environment migrations need to be confirmed.

More info on [Programmatically Executing Commands](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands)